# How to use the trained Caffe model for the current input image?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

Newbie to Caffe.

I am trying to use the trained Convolutional neural network on MNIST dataset using Caffe deep learning framework.

Following the [official tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html).

Steps taken successfully:

```
./data/mnist/get_mnist.sh
./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
./examples/mnist/train_lenet.sh
```

Model was trained and stopped with the following message:

```
I1203 solver.cpp:133] Snapshotting solver state to lenet_iter_10000.solverstate
I1203 solver.cpp:78] Optimization Done.
```

Now, I am not sure as how to get a testing image and use the existing trained model which I believe has been snapshot by the name `lenet_iter_10000.solverstate` to see the predicted scores for each class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `test` function of `caffe`:

```
<path to caffe root>/caffe test -model <val filename>.prototxt -weights lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel
```

As you want to test only one image, give that image as input to your test data layer. Use the `mean_image` as input as well in your `<val filename>.protoxt`. Test batch size is 1 in this case.

Also note that `lenet_iter_10000.solverstate` is not your trained model. Your trained model is actually `lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel`. To know about the diffrence between `solverstate` and `caffemodel` files see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504628/caffe-snapshots-solverstate-vs-caffemodel/36518644#36518644).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am pretty new to this, can you point me as how to use the `mean_image` I am not sure about it. Directing to documentation will also be fine. I understood your solution though I am not sure about the syntax.

Comment: Go to the "Compute Image Mean" section of this link http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html . Once you have computed the image mean, set the path of the mean file obtained above in your train_val.prototxt file in the ```mean_file``` option of the ```transform_param``` node. Also check out this link https://prateekvjoshi.com/2016/02/16/deep-learning-with-caffe-in-python-part-iii-training-a-cnn/ .